# Update Sharepoint List Column Header Connected to a Flow

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I am a very new Power Automate user and my question might sound silly but i'll still try. I have inherited a very complex approval flow which is triggered by a form submission. This flow is connected to an email approval sharepoint lists that contains the approval stages and under them are the email addresses of the approvers per stage. An email is sent to approvers per stage for them to approve the requesr either via teams approval or via email. Any new approval request is being added to another sharepoint list that shows which stage it is in and the status. My question is, if i update the column header names in the sharepoint lists, do i need to update the flow also? If yes, what do i need to check and update? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you won't need to update your flows. SharePoint column names have an internal name and a display name. In flows, the UI shows the display name **but** it uses the internal name in expressions.

[image]

In the example above, you can see the display name is `Last Name` but behind the scenes it uses the internal name `NameLast`.

So when you rename the column name, it will only change the display name, and your flows will not be impacted.